# How to get more renown?

Tags: the-banner-saga

Renown is a key resource in this game.  You can earn it at the end of each battle, but how is it calculated ?  What does it depend on ?  Enemies ?  Losses ?  Current difficulty ?
Is it possible to optimize it, or is it fixed at the beginning of the battle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official wiki](http://bannersaga.gamepedia.com/Renown)

- Defeating enemy units (+1 per unit)
- Rewards for heroic or karmic actions during events (varies).